# PrimaryKeys in Event Sourcing Architecture

Tags: primary-key, uuid, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I got a question regarding id's inside an event sourcing architecture.
Since it's the goal to have a rebuildable state using the eventstore, the data projection should have a deterministic generation of primary keys for the current state data.

e.g.: when i create and then delete an entry afterwards, i save the id of the deleted item into the event store entry. Now when I want to rebuild my state from the Eventstore, the created item event should generate the same id into the projection - to be able to run the deleted event properly.

Does this mean i cannot use random UUID's or am i missing something?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The entity id is the key, the identity stored as part of the stream name. Projections should not generate their own ids, they must use the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a rebuild of your read-model, then you could reset the "counter" that the automatic primary key generation value is based up-on. So that each time you do a rebuild, the primary-key always starts with for example 1.
How that is done depends on the database used.

Alternatively, you could just set the primary key manually using a counter in your code "somehow".